# How to get and store data from different source in SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, merge, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools

I have a XML Source file from which i have to get the "File Name" and a table from which i have to get the file status. Once i get both the values, I need to save the two data in a table.

*XML:*

```
<File>
<File_Info>
    <File_Name>Test1</File_Name>
    <File_Path>BLABLABLA</File_Path>
    <File_Ext>.xml</File_Ext>
</File_Info>
</File>
```

*Table:*

```
FileStatusID  -  Status
1             -  Created
2             -  Processed
```

There are no relationships between these two sources.

How can I store File_Name from XML source and FileStatusID from table to a table?

*File Table:*

```
FileID - FileName - FileStatusID
1      - Test     - 1
2      - Test2    - 1
```

This is my Package

[image]

Comment: save the data into two rows or one row with two columns? If the values are in a variable, you can just use a SQL task

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Thanks for the reply. I'm a newbie in SSIS, could you please elaborate the process?

Comment: Have you managed to get any data out of your xml file and your table? Are you saving the info into a new table? These questions I'm asking - you need should have already considered them and posted them in your question

Comment: @RanjithVaradan just generate two dummy identifier to make a join, you can use script components for that.

Comment: @RanjithVaradan did you try it? or i misunderstood your question??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to merge both data sources based on the order: *First row of XML with first Row of OLEDB*, you can just add a script component transformation after each data source.

On each script component transformation, add an Output Column of type `DT_I4` (integer) *(let's assume that it's name is `AutoNumCol`)*

Write the following script to generate Autonumber, *(i used VB.Net)*:

```
Public Class ScriptMain
    Inherits UserComponent

    Private intID as integer = 0

    Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)

        intID += 1

        Row.AutoNumCol = intID
    End Sub

End Class
```

And use these two column in the Merge Join

*Note make sure that you have marked the script output as `IsSorted`, and changed the `AutoNumCol` SortKeyPosition to `1`:

[image]

[image]